# C++ A custom member compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, compare

Please consider the following piece of code. I am getting a compilation error.  How should I write a custom compare function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>


class X 
{
  public:
    std::vector<std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t> > vec;
    bool cmp(const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d1,
        const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d2);
    void foo(void);
    void print(void);
};

bool X::cmp(const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d1,
    const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d2)
{
  return d1.first < d2.first;
}

void X::foo(void)
{
  vec.push_back(std::make_pair(1000, 100));
  vec.push_back(std::make_pair(800, 200));
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
}

void X::print(void)
{
  for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
  }
}

  int
main()
{
  X x;
  x.foo();
  x.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
 g++ --std=c++11 custom_cmparator.cpp 

 custom_cmparator.cpp: In member function ‘void X::foo()’:
 custom_cmparator.cpp:28:40: error: no matching function for call to       ‘sort(std::vector<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>  >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>  >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
 std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
```

How should I specify
     std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use boost::uint64_t over the types from cstdint?  You already appear to be using C++11.

Comment: This is how the project configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post this as an alternative answer in case you don't want to use a static member function or a non-member one or a lambda, as mentioned in [@Paul's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577311/3093378). You can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) from `#include <functional>` like

```
void X::foo(void)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders; // for _1, _2 etc

    vec.push_back(std::make_pair(1000, 100));
    vec.push_back(std::make_pair(800, 200));
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&X::cmp, this, _1, _2));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make it static member function or non-member at all.

If you need to access class members in your comparator (though your example doesn't need it), you can either use either way mentioned in comments below or such lambda:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [this](const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d1,
           const std::pair<boost::uint64_t, boost::uint64_t>& d2) {
               return this->cmp(d1, d2);
    }
);
```

Comment: If it has to be a member and non static ?

Comment: Use `std::function` and `std::bind`?

Comment: @gudge If you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for a possible implementation, you can see that the call of the predicate is make like any function call, not via a member function, which will require an overload of `std::find` for types like `Object::MemberFunctionPtr`. So, long story short, you cannot use a member function, unless you trick it via e.g. [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Comment: @JamesRoot Can you please explain how ?